# Open ibuffer selected buffers in the same window

Tags: window, ibuffer

Is it possible to tell ibuffer to visit selected buffer in the same window where ibuffer was shown? In my case it always tries to visit buffer in the other window if there are several windows available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With standard configuration the Keys `Enter`, `e` and `f` are calling `ibuffer-visit-buffer` which opens the buffer in the same window. The key `o` runs `ibuffer-visit-buffer-other-window` which opens the buffer in other window.
You can verify this by starting emacs with `emacs -Q`.

If this does not work with your emacs configuration, then you should check your configuration file.

- You could check this with: `M-x customize-group` RET `ibuffer` and then have a look at the Option:  `Ibuffer Use Other Window` it should be set to `nil`.
- Or search in  your configuration file for `ibuffer-use-other-window` the value of this variable should be set to `nil`.

Comment: Thank you, found the root of the cause: it was "window purpose" package that done this silently. I'm actually quite disappointed with because of its invasive and silent behavior...

Comment: This opens the buffer on the splitted window instead of opening it on the current buffer. Is it possible to accomplish it? @jue